# Trigger a downstream project on demand

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Given the following situation

- *main-job* builds and tests a project
- *installer-job* copies artifacts from *main-job*, and packages them into an installer

*installer-job* is set as downstream project of *main-job* via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

But the *installer-job* should only be triggered on-demand from *main-job*'s **build page**.

It's possible to trigger the downstream job on the *project page*:

[image]

But it doesn't seem possible to trigger the build from a **specific build** page.

Is there any option to get such a trigger button on the build page?

Note: It's a freestyle project, not a pipeline one. So things like the [Build Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin) don't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure why is the requirement? Is it like, execute downstream job only in some case/on-demand but if and only if upstream is completed?

Comment: That's exactly it, yes.

Comment: Still unsure exactly what you want / what the question is. You want to suppress running "installer job" from its own project page? Or you want to kick off "installer job" from a specific build of "main job?"

Comment: I want to kick off "installer job" from a specific build of "main job", not only from the project page itself.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without some UI-modifying plugin. Not within the scope of "mere mortals" designing a job. You could do tricks on the installer's parameters page, but that's still a "remember what build you want, go to the launch page, and type it in" scenario. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant solution is possible via the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). "Promotion" is some activity that's performed when a build fulfills certain criteria, like

- build was successful
- all downstream builds passed
- explicit, interactive confirmation

In your case, this condition will be simple: just "main-job" needs be successful, and you will want to confirm explicitly.

There's lots of possible steps that can be triggered as promotion activity -- what you want is to trigger a build of the "installer-job", which can be configured easily.

To summarize, for "main-job", you will configure something like this:
[image]

When you do that, the 'main-job" builds will feature a "Promotion Status" button. After pressing the "Approve" button there, the promotion will be enabled and the "install-job" will start building:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution I have been using for the last weeks, and it seems like there's no better way. One issue is that I cannot use ${PROMOTED_JOB_NAME} et al. in the downstream job (because they are only available in the promotion job). Do you have any idea for this issue?

Comment: You could pass the required parameters explicitly. If you use the "Trigger/call builds on other projects" action, you can add custom parameters to the triggered build. The same is possible with a groovy action or when using a shell script that triggers the downstream via REST.